# Create own Proxy server on hosting web server (Apache, nginx, django, node)

Tags: node.js, apache, web, proxy, system-administration

Hello to all stack users.

Our provider has blocked many sites. I tried to buy a VPS/VDS server. But many VPS, VDS servers are blocked. I didn't find a working VPS/VDS server.

So, can I buy a hosting to use this hosting as a proxy.
I will use this proxy to connect the vpn server.
Hosting can be on Apache, node or Django.
I have searched a lot but have not found answers to these questions.

Or can i configure hosting to use like a doh server?
any information would be of great help to me.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean your ISP (internet service provider) has blocked many site access and you would like to use a proxy server to interact with those web sites?

Comment: @mikrowdev yes.